# Testing Heartbeat controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, heartbeat

I'm currently writing tests for an app using cucumber and rspec. I was asked to test the heartbeat controller, but I'm not really sure how to approach it.

```
module Api
    class HeartbeatController < ActionController::Base
        respond_to :json, :xml

        include Something::Status

        def status
            respond_with status_response
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec may help get you started. Although I personally just test the model and then use integration tests to test the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just visited the xml and json paths and checked for certain distinct keywords to make sure it was responding the way I expected it to.